# 400 Bad Request uploading to Amazon S3 with signed request

Tags: javascript, ajax, amazon-s3, http-status-code-403, http-status-code-400

I am developing a webapp in Django and React, deployed on Heroku, for which file storage is needed. As recommended by Heroku, I am using Amazon S3. However, I seem to be unable to upload files to my S3 bucket from the frontend. As per these instructions: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python, I first ask the backend for a signed request. (I was able to set this up nicely in Python without any issues using boto3). Then I use the signed information to try and upload the actual file to S3. But when doing so, I keep getting 400 Bad Request errors.

What's also strange is that I had to enable public access to get a 400 error, as I used to experience **403 Forbidden** errors, even with the signed credentials.

Here is my code:

```
const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
const file_name = file.name
const file_type = file.type
const body = JSON.stringify({ file_name, file_type });
axios.post('/api/triggers/create/video/sign_request', body, config)
.then(res => {
  let content = {}
  for (var key in res.data.data.fields) {
    content[key] = res.data.data.fields[key]
  }
  content['file'] = file
  const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': file.type } }
  axios.put(res.data.data.url, content, config)
  //...
})
```

I prefer to use axios, but I tried the following code as well, which was used in the Heroku tutorial above. Unfortunately this yields the same results.

```
const file_name = file.name
const file_type = file.type
const body = JSON.stringify({ file_name, file_type });
axios.post('/api/triggers/create/video/sign_request', body, config)
.then(res => {
  var fd = new FormData()
  for (var key in res.data.data.fields) {
    fd.append(key, res.data.data.fields[key])
  }
  fd.append('file', file)
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', res.data.data.url, true);
  xhr.send(fd)
  //...
})
```

The credentials used to sign the request are associated with an IAM user that has full access to S3.[image]

The signed request I get back from my Django backend looks like this:

```
{
    "data": {
        "url": "https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/",
        "fields": {
            "acl": "public-read",
            "Content-Type": "video/mp4",
            "key": "funnycatisfunny.mp4",
            "AWSAccessKeyId": "BLABLABLAACCESSKEYBLABLABLA",
            "policy": "eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMjAtMDQtMDJUMTU6NDg6MTlaIiwgEtceteraEtCeterA",
            "signature": "S1GnAtuREWdleI4WXv5WHEBjc="
        }
    },
    "url": "https://my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/funnycatisfunny.mp4"
}
```

I used to experience issues due to CORS, but those went away after specifying the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I figured that maybe the problem was a result of the S3 bucket lacking a policy, so I specified one:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:Put*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

That didn't change things either.

Can't wrap my head around this one. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**: As it turns out, I PUT the file at the wrong url, namely the bucket url, whereas one should always PUT to *bucketurl/filename*. Adjusting this allowed me to upload a file to S3. However, as soon as I block public access again, I get served a **403 Forbidden** as before.

Comment: It seems to me your key does not have needed permissions to execute the request

Comment: I switched the IAM user credentials with my AWS root credentials, but access is denied regardless. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to use the `S3Client` from `@aws-sdk/client-s3` with the [`PutObjectCommand`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/Package/-aws-sdk-client-s3/Class/PutObjectCommand/) to upload objects:

```js
await s3Client.send(new PutObjectCommand(
{
  Bucket: string;
  Key: string;
  Body: File;
  Metadata: { string: string };
}
))
```

I also got `400 Bad Request` and it turned out that the `MetaData` I was trying to send was too big. Be careful! - user-defined object `MetaData` is [limited to 2kb](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html?icmpid=docs_amazons3_console#object-metadata:%7E:text=ascii%3A%20AMAZONS3-,Note,bytes%20in%20the%20UTF%2D8%20encoding%20of%20each%20key%20and%20value.,-For%20information%20about).